# How to shrink height of UILabels if needed via Auto Layout

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout

I have several `UILabels` laid out on my View Controller. While working in Portrait mode, I have increased the height of each label so that the boundaries are all touching - they're stacked on top of each other without any spacing in-between. I have a big title and button located at the top and bottom. I have already fixed the top title to always be centered at the top, and the bottom button fixed to the bottom. I also have fixed the middle label to be vertically and horizontally centered in the view. That's all working great. My problem is, I can't seem to figure out how to get the labels to all fit on screen and mostly vertical centered collectively when the height is reduced. I would like it to reduce the height of each label as needed (but not too short such that the text is clipped). I've tried pinning the heights and then changing them to less than or equal to, but in doing so it wants to update the frame to remove the extra height, causing the buttons to no longer be stacked right on top of each other. Then if I set vertical spacing constraints, it will be fixed so it will result in the labels too close together in Portrait if I use the standard value, or if I go with a fixed number they won't adjust to fit in Landscape.

What do I need to do in order to have the labels expanded to fill most of the view when in Portrait, shrink a bit on a 3.5" screen, then really shrink when in Landscape? The labels should all be centered collectively, based off that middle label that's always centered. This is basically what I'd like to obtain:

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is set the label's heights to be equal to one another. Then provide constraints for distances between each label, and between L/R sides and top/bottom sides. This way, the labels will shrink when the screen height shrinks.

Comment: Thanks, that's working beautifully for the 3.5" screen. When I rotate to landscape, it does work good except the top and bottom labels aren't constrained within the desired area. The top label is located at the top of the screen above the Title and the bottom is at the bottom of the screen on top of the button. I know this is because there is no relationship between the labels and title/button. So I set up Vertical Spacing for those, but now they're all squished - the title and labels are clipped - height too small, even though there's extra space below the title and above the button.